# store and restore struct in file in C

Tags: c, file, struct, restore

I need to store a struct in a file and read it back to return it then.
I would try to write it to the file like this:

```
void lld_tpWriteCalibration(struct cal cal) {
    FIL fdst;      /* file objects */
   UINT bw;        /* File write count */

    /* Create destination file on the drive 0 */
    wf_open(&fdst, "0:calibration.txt", FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
    wf_write(&fdst, cal, sizeof(cal), &bw);

    wf_close(&fdst);
}
```

Would that work?
And how can I read it back and return it from this function?

```
struct cal lld_tpReadCalibration(void) {

}
```

The struct is:

```
   struct cal {
       float xm; 
       float ym; 
       float xn; 
       float yn; 
   };
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As mystic meg is not in the room - what is `struct cal`?

Comment: wf_open and wf_write aren't standard C functions, so I can't say whether the code works or not.  But the code looks close enough to a standard fopen/fwrite/fclose sequence that it probably does work.  The reader function would use whatever the analog of fread() is.  I do not understand however why three people have upvoted this ill-defined question.

Comment: that functions are indeed compatible to the standard C functions. But when I did read the bytes back, how do I re-assemble it to a struct? Or do I just read it back into a buffer and return the buffer?

Comment: So have you tried wf_read or whatever it is called?  There's no obvious reason why it wouldn't work to read back what you wrote to the file.  Any problem is likely to be due to the data no longer being valid.  Re-reading pointers, for example, is likely not to sense between runs of a program.  But if it's just strings or timestamps or similarly independent data then reading it back in should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve your structure the same way you stored it.

```
read(&fdst, &cal, sizeof(cal));
```

But you got to be careful, you won't be able to do this on every architecture because of [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problem.

Comment: On any given platform, you can do read and write such files safely.  What you won't be able to do is move data written like this to a different type of machine (a different CPU) with any confidence.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be OK with that structure and that writing/reading technique if you only try to read the file on the same type of machine as you write it on. The data written like that is not reliably portable across different types of machines.